# Training and Testing Model PollyPlot

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-science

I'm trying to plot a Polynomial Plot with Matplotlib/Seaborn. I am new to Data Science and thus I'm having trouble with this bit of code:

```
def PollyPlot(xtrain, xtest, y_train, y_test, lr,poly_transform):
    width = 12
    height = 10
    plt.figure(figsize=(width, height))
    
    
    #training data 
    #testing data 
    # lr:  linear regression object 
    #poly_transform:  polynomial transformation object 
 
    xmax=max([xtrain.values.max(), xtest.values.max()])

    xmin=min([xtrain.values.min(), xtest.values.min()])

    x=np.arange(xmin, xmax, 0.1)


    plt.plot(xtrain, y_train, 'ro', label='Training Data')
    plt.plot(xtest, y_test, 'go', label='Test Data')
    plt.plot(x, lr.predict(poly_transform.fit_transform(x.reshape(-1, 1))), label='Predicted Function')
    plt.ylim([-10000, 60000])
    plt.ylabel('Price')
    plt.legend()
```

This is the function that plots the polynomial function. However when I call the function with:

```
PollyPlot(x_train[['horsepower']], x_test[['horsepower']], y_train, y_test, poly, pr)
```

I get the following error:

```
InvalidIndexError: (slice(None, None, None), None)
```

Any assistance given would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done 2 changes:

1. I've removed from the function the .values. to calculate the max and min because I will convert the xtrain and xtest to numpy:

   def PollyPlot(xtrain, xtest, y_train, y_test, lr,poly_transform):
   width = 12
   height = 10
   plt.figure(figsize=(width, height))

   ```
    #training data 
    #testing data 
    # lr:  linear regression object 
    #poly_transform:  polynomial transformation object 

    xmax=max([xtrain.max(), xtest.max()])

    xmin=min([xtrain.min(), xtest.min()])

    x=np.arange(xmin, xmax, 0.1)


    plt.plot(xtrain, y_train, 'ro', label='Training Data')
    plt.plot(xtest, y_test, 'go', label='Test Data')
    plt.plot(x, lr.predict(poly_transform.fit_transform(x.reshape(-1, 1))), label='Predicted Function')
    plt.ylim([-10000, 60000])
    plt.ylabel('Price')
    plt.legend()
   ```
2. To execute I have converted x_train and x_test to numpy:

   PollyPlot(x_train[['horsepower']].to_numpy(), x_test[['horsepower']].to_numpy(), y_train.to_numpy(), y_test.to_numpy(), poly,pr)